Creating a Staging environment - getting a no such table error
I'm migrating from one server to another.  Copy is a stage version.
After restore, I clear the cache tables in civicrm, reload the web site and I get this error:
[09-Aug-2024 14:49:49 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [-18: DB Error: no such table
thrown in /home/stage.sdda.ca/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 974
For the life of me, I cannot find what table its actually looking for?  The above is in the php_errors.log file.  Is there somewhere else I can look for more information?

I digged a bit deeper and found that my backup/restore software does NOT recreate the table views!  I will need to resolve that manually.
